# Does Paramiko works with ScaleFT?

Tags: paramiko

ScaleFT using certificated based Authentication for ssh,  and according to the documentation, it issues ephemeral credentials which expire in few minutes, https://www.scaleft.com/docs/sshkeys/ 
I am investigating the possibility of using the ephemeral credentials which scaleft generated and wondering if anyone has been able to use python Paramiko to build ssh connections with ScaleFT enabled? 
I am not sure if the ephemeral credentials are available to user or not. Moreover, even if the ephemeral credentials can be found and used , when the certs expired, will it causes unstable connections?